# Model object is prints nothing

Tags: php, yii, model

```
$model=new TestCheck;
print_r($_POST['TestCheck']);
```

It prints the follows error :

> Undefined index: TestCheck

I Am using this in if condition so When I open create page its shows empty / blank page there is no form. Please help to sort out this.

Thanks in advance,
Sally

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want to know how you parse form data with PHP, start [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). If you want to print Yii model data properties, then just use the `$model` variable you just assigned a model to and not the `$_POST` array.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/44sSnczh  I have pasted here my controller, create function, create page not showing form rather it shows blank page as am a new to yii1 can you help me to sort-out it??

Comment: You can edit your question and include code. See these links to learn how you can add/edit question code: [How to post code in SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51106/how-to-post-code-in-so), [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). You get the error because the post data do not contain any `TestCheck` variable. Can you share the html form code?

Comment: update your question and add  all the code related  to this action